# FlowLayout Control With User Control Item Template Not Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Please could you help with the following...

For custom pop up dialogue purposes I wish to structure my WPF application along the lines of:

```
Window > Grid > User Control > FlowLayout > Data Template > User Control
```

... where the brace represents "contains"

I have a model `MyType.cs`, the contents of which I would like to be displayed in the final user control `UserControl2.xaml`

I have a **ViewModel** `ViewMod.cs` for this model, and a **ViewModel** for the list of these **ViewModels** `ListViewModel.cs`

I set the **ItemSource** property of the **FlowLayoutControl** in `UserControl1.cs` after programatically creating **UserControl1** and setting it's data context

As far as I can tell from debugging, the parsing of my list of **ViewModels** is working, however I am unsure how to return the data from **MyType** as when requesting the data context of the bound **UserControl2** returns null

...

Apologies if my requirements are unclear. This is my first attempt at WPF and any help would be greatly appreciated

[SOLUTION FILES](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8lZcsIZC6RVVmxiX3FNNVdBY0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
public UserControl2() {
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += (sender, args) => {
    var obj = (ViewMod)this.DataContext;
    if (obj == null || obj.Prop == null)
      return;
    var d = obj.Prop;
    if (d == null)
      return;
    grd2.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = d.Name });
  };
}
```

`DataContext` is not set instantly. Hence we use the `Loaded` event and add a lambda to it to do your corresponding steps.

**side-note:**

even-though this works, please do search and look at some MVVM examples. While having no code-behind is not really an MVVM requirement, I think your taking it a bit too far adding Grid children and stuff from code-behind when you can do it perfectly fine from xaml.